# How is my Ajax PHP filter not filtering records with PDO?

Tags: jquery, ajax, filter, pdo, where-in

So I am trying to filter records using checkboxes with Ajax and PHP. I am trying to filter records with PDO, since it is the safest option. I am wondering why the filter system only filters when one checkbox is selected and not more.

This is my code:

```
        if(isset($_POST['merk'])) 
        { 
            // Pretty sure you have the following format 1,2,3,4 and not '1','2','3','4'
            $merk = implode(',', $_POST['merk']);
            if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $merk)) {
                // Notice that placeholders should not be quoted
                $sql .= ' AND merk IN(:merk)';
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['brandstof'])) 
        {
            $brandstof = implode(',', $_POST['brandstof']);
            if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $brandstof)) {
                $sql .= ' AND brandstof IN(:brandstof)';
            }
        }

        if(isset($_POST['carrosserie'])) 
        {
            $carrosserie = implode(',', $_POST['carrosserie']);
            if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $carrosserie)) {
                $sql .= ' AND carrosserie IN(:carrosserie)';
            }
        }
```

If the checkbox `merk` is selected that code will execute. Is there something wrong with the query maybe?

```
//We prepare our SELECT statement.
$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        
if(isset($_POST['merk']))
{
  $statement->bindParam(":merk", $merk);
  // $params[] .= $merk;
}

if(isset($_POST['brandstof']))
{
  $statement->bindParam(":brandstof", $brandstof);
  // $params[] .= $brandstof;
}

if(isset($_POST['carrosserie']))
{
  $statement->bindParam(":carrosserie", $carrosserie);
  // $params[] .= $carrosserie;
}
    
$statement->execute();
```

This code filters one checkbox input, but stops filtering when two checkboxes are selected. See example below.

[image: When one checkbox is selected]

[image: When second checkbox is selected]

So my POST Data looks like this:  `Array ( [0] => BMW [1] => Skoda )`

Comment: Check for an SQL error. You're currently working blindly, without error handling.

Comment: @Mitya See example above

Comment: I don't see any error handling in your code. You need to check the SQL query you're building is valid. Everything else is irrelevant at this point.

Comment: @Mitya I have error handling at the top of my code which I did not include. ini_set('display_errors', '1');
        ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
        error_reporting(E_ALL); There are no errors in the query.

Comment: These two seems very wrong: `$merk = implode("','", $_POST['merk']);` and `$merk = "'".$merk."'";`. Shouldn't this be `$merk = implode(',', $_POST['merk']);` and then do not add single quotes to merk e.g keep it as it is from the $_POST array, since `'data'` and `data` is not the same and I guess you are looking for the later.

Comment: @Cyclonecode The reason I did that is because that will give single quotes to every value inside the merk array. That is needed for the IN() clause. I need those single quotes.

Comment: Hey @Muwaheed_Nabil, The code example is good, it has some small flaws that you can easily fix, here are things I found:
1- When you add every parameter to the $params array you are using the string concatenation operator (The dot operator) where it is an array not a string. Use `$params[] = $item;` not `$param[] .= $item;`

Comment: @AmirIskander But there are no records shown so there is something wrong?

Comment: 2- You either use execute() with all params and values or bindParam() with use execute with no params not both.

Comment: So you can remove the `$params` setting and rely only on execute() without any parameters.

Comment: @Muwaheed_Nabil What is the data type of `@_POST['merk']`, `@_POST['carrosserie']` and `@_POST['brandstof']`?

Comment: Check the examples [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)

Comment: @AmirIskander The data types of @_POST['merk'], @_POST['carrosserie'] and @_POST['brandstof'] are Varchar

Comment: @AmirIskander Must I remove the $params setting and only rely on bindparam for it to work?

Comment: @AmirIskander It did not work to remove the params setting and binding param, and replace it with $statement->execute(array(":merk" => $merk_array))

Comment: @Muwaheed_Nabil I can help you with this in chat instead: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/227474/65762959?tab=general

Comment: @Cyclonecode I don't have 20 reputation yet hahah

Comment: @Muwaheed_Nabil For the sample code in the question, keep the calls to `bindParam` as is and remove all the statements like `$params[] .= $carrosserie;` and for the last statement remove the `$params` parameter to be `$statement->execute();`

Comment: @AmirIskander I have just edited my previous code. Take a look above. It doesn't work still (see example)

Comment: @AmirIskander Do you have any idea?

Comment: @AmirIskander bro can you add me on instagram so we can talk about this. I've been bothering for so long

Comment: @Cyclonecode Add me on instagram

Comment: Instagram? Nah, you can always email me if you need help.

Comment: @Cyclonecode What is your email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using strange quotes e.g `"','"` when parsing the input. Also, you should not quote the actual placeholder in the statement.
After talking in chat I realised that the problem is the IN clauses and `bindParams()` not supporting arrays.

From the [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) for PDOStatement::execute:

> input_parameters An array of values with as many elements as there are
> bound parameters in the SQL statement being executed. All values are
> treated as PDO::PARAM_STR.
>
> Multiple values cannot be bound to a single parameter; for example, it
> is not allowed to bind two values to a single named parameter in an
> IN() clause.

In order to fix this you will need to change your code to something like this:

```
// Enable error reporting to spot any warnings and errors.
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$params = array();

// Creates an IN clause with placeholders and stores parameters
function createInParam(array $data, $name, $query, array &$params) {
  $query .= " AND $name IN (";
  foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    $params[$name . '_' . $key] = $value;
    $query .= ":${name}_${key},";
  }
  return rtrim($query, ',') . ')';
}

// Bind all parameters to statement
function bindParams($statement, array $params) {
  foreach ($params as $key => $value) {
    $statement->bindParam(":$key", $params[$key]);
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['merk'])) { 
  $merk = implode(',', $_POST['merk']);
  if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $merk)) {
    $data = explode(',', $merk);
    $sql = createInParam($data, 'merk', $sql, $params);
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['brandstof'])) {
  $brandstof = implode(',', $_POST['brandstof']);
  if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $brandstof)) {
    $data = explode(',', $brandstof);
    $sql = createInParam($data, 'brandstof', $sql, $params);
  }
}
    
if (isset($_POST['carrosserie'])) {
  $carrosserie = implode(',', $_POST['carrosserie']);
  if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $carrosserie)) {
    $data = explode(',', $carrosserie);
    $sql = createInParam($data, 'carrosserie', $sql, $params);
  }
}

// Then bind all parameters and execute
bindParams($statement, $params);
if ($statement->execute()) {
  // Success
}
```

Another way of doing the same thing would be:

```
$params = array();


if (isset($_POST['merk'])) { 
  $merk = implode(',', $_POST['merk']);
  if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $merk)) {
    $inClause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['merk']), '?'));
    $sql .= " AND merk IN ($inClause)";
    $params = array_merge($params, explode(',', $merk));
  }
}

if (isset($_POST['brandstof'])) {
  $brandstof = implode(',', $_POST['brandstof']);
  if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $brandstof)) {
    $inClause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['brandstof']), '?'));
    $sql .= " AND brandstof IN ($inClause)";
    $params = array_merge($params, explode(',', $brandstof));
  }
}
    
if (isset($_POST['carrosserie'])) {
  $carrosserie = implode(',', $_POST['carrosserie']);
  if (preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $carrosserie)) {
    $inClause = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($_POST['carrosserie']), '?'));
    $sql .= " AND carrosserie IN ($inClause)";
    $params = array_merge($params, explode(',', $carrosserie));
  }
}

if ($statement->execute($params)) {
  // Success
}
```

Comment: So happy someone helped with the filtering problem I face for over two weeks now... Thanks for giving a great answer. The filtering system works for one checkbox input now. But when I try to filter records based on two inputs, it gives me no records. See example above

Comment: Well you need to update your question with how the actual $_POST data looks for the different filters. Like I said you can always email me at cyclonecode@gmail.com or connect to my slack at https://join.slack.com/t/cyclonecode/shared_invite/zt-6bdtbdab-n9QaMLM~exHP19zFDPN~AQ and I'll try to help you. Thinking that it might be easier just chatting about this instead. If the above helped you please also give it an upvote =)

Comment: Your edited answer above works great! Thanks for helping me